# Testfor a written book in 1.8 with custom name and writing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I’m working on a map and need help with the `Testfor` command. I’ve looked around and tried out several different things and just messed around with the command without help, but I can’t get it to activate with the book in hand. Here’s the command I have set up, but it doesn’t work.

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItemSlot:8,Inventory:[{Slot:8b,id:minecraft:written_book,tag:{pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"Master, I have done as you told me, Minera will soon fall to your Undead Army. I still have not figured out how to obtain the sword, but you were right to check the bookshelf before attempting more drastic measures... (the note is torn)\"}]"],display:{Name:"Torn Note"}}}]}
```

Now here's a different version, but without a book (this one works perfectly).

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItemSlot:8,Inventory:[{Slot:8b,tag:{display:{Name:"Torn Note"}}}]}
```

My problem is that with a book the second command doesn’t light up and I really want to use a book for this part of my map.

Also I should say, the command for the book itself should be fine, I used a JSON Minecraft generator and it works fine with `/give`. I did edit the format slightly to try to get the `testfor` command to work, but it didn’t.

Comment: I can't test it right now, so I'll just post this as a comment, but can't you just remove the "tag" tag from the first command? or if your trying to test for a particular book, can't you just test for the name, not the pages?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your pages tag

Comment: In 1.12 `id:"minecraft:written_book"` work

Answer (score 1):

Better not be using the "pages" tag for testfor'ing books. pages uses JSON format, and there are many valid JSON formats for a book, and you couldn't detect them all. Use a custom NBT tag to detect a specific book, or instead just use the book name.